# a question about negative number mod

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, inverse

I was reading a note about modular arithmetic, it says that if $x+y=0$,, then the additive inverse of $x$ is $y$, -1 mod 3=2, since 1+2=0.
I'm confused, what does 1+2=0 related to  -1 mod 3?

Another question is that you know we can check the table to get the additive inverse
[image]

for example, 1 mod 3=2 since 1+2=0 mod 3 where we can locate from the table, but how can we do the same thing on -1 mod 2=0, do we just get rid of "-" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two numbers are equivalent modulo 3 if you can write one of them as a multiple of 3 plus the other. That is: $a\equiv b\mod 3$ means $a=3k+b$.

In the examples you gave we have: $(1+2)\equiv0\mod3$ because $1+2=3=3(1)+0$.
So you can say that $2$ and $1$ are the additive inverse of each other in this structure.

A way to denote that is writing $2=-1$ but this one may lead to confusion. 
So another way to say the same thing is $-1\equiv2\mod3$ which means that $-1=-3+2=3(-1)+2$. In this case we can also verify that $-1$ and $-2$ are the additive inverses of each other.

Comment: B.Brebs  Would the inverse of 1 same as -1?

Comment: Um, 1 + (-1) = 0 mod 3 so they are inverses.  2 = -1 mod 3 so the are both equivalent and both inverses.

Comment: So it's not the "same" as -1 but it is *equivalent* to -1.  And 2 is equivalent to -1 mod 3 so every thing is hunky dory.  The inverse of 1 is 2 which is equivalent to -1.  No problems.

Comment: you're right. I was doing it on my head, but I can't quite think without paper.